# AWK replace a big string with a part of it in one column (cut a part of it), and print all other columns intact, keeping the formatting

Tags: awk, sed, replace, split, cut

I want to replace a big string with a part of it - text from the second slash "/" in the column 2.
Also the formatting should be maintained.

My text is

```
99-AAA-9999 |  ZZZ/AAA/999999/AAA/99.99.9999                        |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  ZZZ/AAAA AAAA/999999/AAA/99.99.9999                  |            |       9.99 |    9999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  ZZZ/AA AAAAAAA/999999/AAA/99.99.9999                 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  ZZZ/AAA AAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAAA/999999/AAA/99.99.9999   |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  ZZZ/AAAA AAAAAA AAAAA/999999/AAA/99.99.9999          |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
```

I want it like this after cutting off the text from ZZZ/AA..... upto the second slash "/" with good formatting

```
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |    9999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
```

Actually there are many other columns, but I have provided only sample data.
Note : All the text and numbers are not the same.

Please guide me how to do it using awk or sed, preferably awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's:[^ /]*/[^/]*/\([^|]*[^ |]\) *|:\1 |:' file
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |    9999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
99-AAA-9999 |  999999/AAA/99.99.9999 |            |       9.99 |   99999.99 |
```

Comment: **Excellent** @EdMorton sir.  Can you explain a bit, please?

Comment: Not much to explain - is there any particular part of it you don't understand?

Comment: how the formatting is effected, I am unable to understand

Comment: `[^ /]*/[^/]*/` matches `ZZZ/AAAA AAAA/`, for example, while `\([^|]*[^ |]\)` matches **and captures** `999999/AAA/99.99.9999` and ` |` matches the trailing blanks plus `|` so then when you replace all of that with `\1 |` you're just putting back what you captured followed by ` |` and discarding what was before and after it.

Comment: Thank you very much.  You have always been helpful to me.